# What is the difference of "dom_content_loaded.histogram.bin.start/end" in Google's BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, histogram, html, domcontentloaded

I need to build a histogram, concerning DOMContentLoaded of a webpage. When I used BigQuery, I noticed that apart from density, there are 2 more attributes (start, end). In my head there should only be 1 attribute, the *DOMContentLoaded* event is only fired when the DOM has loaded.

Can anyone help clarify the difference of *.start* and *.stop*? These attributes always have 100 milliseconds difference between them (if **start = X ms**, then **stop = X+100 ms**. See a query example posted below.

I can not understand what these attributes represent exactly:

`dom_content_loaded.histogram.bin.START`

AND

`dom_content_loaded.histogram.bin.END`

> **Q**: Which one of them represents the time that the DOMContentLoaded event
>   is fired in a user's browser?

```
SELECT
    bin.START AS start,
    bin.END AS endd
FROM
    `chrome-ux-report.all.201809`,
    UNNEST(dom_content_loaded.histogram.bin) AS bin
WHERE
    origin = 'https://www.google.com'
```

**Output:**

```
Row |start | end    
1    0       100
2    100     200
3    200     300
4    300     400
[...]
```

Comment: What dataset are you talking about

Comment: `chrome-ux-report.all.201809`

Comment: I'll suggest you to post a query

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich - have you read my answer? - It already  answers your question - Please read the answer again :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below explains meaning of bin.start, bin.end and bin.density

Run below SELECT statement

```
SELECT
  origin, 
  effective_connection_type.name type_name, 
  form_factor.name factor_name,
  bin.start AS bin_start,
  bin.end AS bin_end,
  bin.density AS bin_density
FROM `chrome-ux-report.all.201809`,
  UNNEST(dom_content_loaded.histogram.bin) AS bin
WHERE origin = 'https://www.google.com'
```

You will get 1550 rows in result

below are first 5 rows

```
Row origin                  type_name   factor_name bin_start   bin_end bin_density  
1   https://www.google.com  4G          phone       0           100     0.01065  
2   https://www.google.com  4G          phone       100         200     0.01065  
3   https://www.google.com  4G          phone       200         300     0.02705  
4   https://www.google.com  4G          phone       300         400     0.02705  
5   https://www.google.com  4G          phone       400         500     0.0225
```

You can read them as: 
for phone with 4G load of dom_content was loaded within 100 milliseconds for 1.065% of loads; in between 100 and 200 milliseconds for 1.065%; in between 200 and 300 milliseconds for 2.705% and so on

To summarize for each origin, type and factor you got histogram that is represented as a repeated record with start and end of each bin along with density which represents percentage of respective user experience

Note: if you add up the dom_content_loaded densities across all dimensions for a single origin, you will get 1 (or a value very close to 1 due to approximations).

For example

```
SELECT SUM(bin.density) AS total_density
FROM `chrome-ux-report.all.201809`,
  UNNEST(dom_content_loaded.histogram.bin) AS bin
WHERE origin = 'https://www.google.com'
```

returns

```
Row total_density    
1   0.9995999999999978
```

Hope this helped

Comment: consider also voting up answer (if not yet) :o)